# how i can return variable from app.component.ts to another home page ts ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a function in `app.componts.ts` I want to return value to `home.ts`

how I can do this in ionic 3

I have tried with [events API](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/util/Events/)

and tried [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-g9oo6n?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts) as well

so how i can return variable from `app.component.ts` to another home page ts ionic 3

Answer (score 0):

Create SharedProvider for save global variable over the all app.

**sharedProvider.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharedProvider {
   x:string = '';
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class MyApp {

    constructor(private sharedProvider:SharedProvider) {
        this.sharedProvider.x = 'someValue';
    }
}
```

**homePage.ts**

```
 export class HomePage {

    constructor(private sharedProvider:SharedProvider) {
        console.log('x value: ', this.sharedProvider.x);
    }
}
```